# Apply a parent to an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have fixed the video's height and width ratio using [FluidVids.js](http://toddmotto.com/fluid-and-responsive-youtube-and-vimeo-videos-with-fluidvids-js/). Now I want to wrap my iframe with a parent. I know that the parents working by manually throwing it inside the HTML-file. But the template I am working on needs to do this automatically.

So what I'm asking for is a (pure) JavaScript for wrapping my iframe with a div class I call `fwparent`. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="post">
...
<iframe src="a-nice-video" allowFullscreen></iframe>
...
</div>
```

FluidVids overrides the standard sizes on the iframe. But my div class `post` has some paddings that I need to override with the `fwparent` class!

So the result should be something like this:

```
<div class="post">
...
<div class="fwparent"><iframe src="a-nice-video" allowFullscreen></iframe></div>
...
</div>
```

**And remember, pure JavaScript. No extra HTTP requests for jQuery or stuff like that...**

I have no experience what-so-ever with JavaScript. So be nice ;)

I have something similar which applies to images:

```
function imgWrap(parent) {
if (!parent || parent.nodeType !== 1) {
    return false;
}
else {
    var images = parent.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        newDiv = document.createElement('div'),
        tmp;
    newDiv.className = 'parent';
    for (var i = 0, len = images.length; i < len; i++) {
        tmp = newDiv.cloneNode(true);
        parent.insertBefore(tmp, images[i])
        tmp.appendChild(images[i]);
    }
}
}

imgWrap(document.querySelector('div.post'));
```

And jQuery does something like this:

```
$('iframe').wrap('<div class="fwparent" />');
```

But I want it to be pure JavaScript. And apply to **all** iframes...

Comment: What have you tried so far? I know you don't want to _use_ jQuery, but that doesn't mean you can't look within jquery.js to see how it implements its [`.wrap()` method](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)...

Comment: There is a code snippet which applies to images...

Comment: OK, regarding your update, it should work essentially the same way for your iframe if you just change `img` to `iframe`...

Comment: It should, but I've already tried it. The problem is the code inside the for argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var div = document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
div.className = 'fwparent';
div.appendChild(document.getElementById('iframe'));
```

**EDIT**

To wrap more than one `iframe` you need to use a loop:

```
var frms = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe'),
    post = document.getElementById('post'),
    div, n;
for (n = 0; n < frms.length; n++) {
    div = post.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
    div.className = 'fwparent';
    div.appendChild(frms[0]); // *
}
```

`*` = looks like we need `0` instead of `n` here, a live nodelist created by `getElementsByTagName()` is updated when appending `iframes` to a new location.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MpNYZ/).

Comment: Didn't work, tried fixing the tag names without success... (It's an iframe not a frame)

Comment: I tested this with Chrome, FF and IE10 before posting answer, worked well in all those browsers. Are you sure the elements involved exist?

Comment: @Youbet `frame` is the ID of the element, not the tag name. Here is a fiddle of it working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ZycyZ/

Comment: I don't see where the wrapper comes from... And the fwparent doesn't apply itself to the iframe tag.
EDIT: Just saw your jsfiddle.net, ignore this...

Comment: @Blade0rz Thanks for the fiddle, I was just building up mine, but seems not needed now : ).

Comment: @Youbet There's no `id` for the `iframe` in your fiddle. Just add the `id="frame"`, and your fiddle works as expected.

Comment: The problem is still there, it needs to apply to all iframes. Not just the iframes with the id="frame". That will not work the way I need it to :/

Comment: @Youbet You should have mention this in your question, there you're talking about one iframe only. Are there more than one `div.post`s , or are all iframes within that single `div`.

Comment: All iframes are inside the "post" div class, it's the container